# Make links all the same width

Tags: html, forms, css, button

I have buttons that change width according to the text inside the buttons. How do I make them all the same width? 
I've tried editing the css and adding 
`min-width:100px and width:100px;` but it doesn't work.

```css
a {
  min-height: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 6px 13px 5px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
div {
  z-index: 7;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-height: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
  line-height: 38px;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-size: 24px;
  left: 1148px;
  top: 425px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -0.0025, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="tp-button red small">MIT</a>

<div class="tp-caption noshadow tp-fade tp-resizeme start" data-x="center" data-hoffset="200" data-y="bottom" data-voffset="-50" data-speed="300" data-start="500" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1"
data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-endspeed="300"><a href="#" class="tp-button red small">Brandies</a>
```

Comment: Add width:100px; display:block; to the CSS for your anchor tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Links are `inline` by default. Simply set them to `inline-block` so widths will be applied.

```
a.tp-button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: if I add this then the text is not within the box, it displays under it.

Comment: You can see it on http://testsitemg.com/meor-boston/ the buttons over the video I would like in uniform width